# How to show call screen when app is in background or terminate using linphone ios

Tags: ios, swift, linphone

I want to make call app in iOS by using SIP or `linphone` library.I have searched a lot but not found any solution.On `linphone` site help I create below code but in this code, I found an error.Is this code is working or not.I don't know what is

**while !linphone_proxy_config_is_registered(- proxy_cfg // how to get this in linphone) && i < 40** .

How to show incoming call screen when the app is in the background or terminate using the linphone library in iOS swift.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
{
    linphone_core_refresh_registers(theLinphone.lc)
    //wait for registration answer

    var i: Int = 0
    while !linphone_proxy_config_is_registered(proxy_cfg) && i < 40 {
        i += 1
        linphone_core_iterate(theLinphone.lc)
        usleep(100000)
    }
    i += 1
    //register keepalive handler
    UIApplication.shared.setKeepAliveTimeout(600, handler: {() -> Void in
        //refresh sip registration
        linphone_core_refresh_registers(theLinphone.lc)
        //make sure sip REGISTER is sent
        linphone_core_iterate(theLinphone.lc)
    })

    if application.applicationState != .active {
        var notif = UILocalNotification()

        notif.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: 0)
        notif.alertBody = "New incoming call"
        notif.alertAction = "Answer"
        notif.soundName = "oldphone-mono-30s.caf"
        UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notif)

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No, I didn't find an answer.

Comment: I found this earlier https://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__IOS.html but it doesn't explain how to adjust linphone for tcp, instead of udp. Then I saw that setKeepAliveTimeout was replaced with pushkit which looks like it can be used to wake up the app when in background.

Comment: can I have use push kit with Sip calling by using linphone library?